# PHP: stored string date into MySQL date format, but the stored date turns out to be 1969-12-31

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password, $str_birthday) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted_password"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
    $tmp_dobformat = split('-', $str_birthday);
    $tmp = $tmp_dobformat[2].'-'.$tmp_dobformat[1].'-'.$tmp_dobformat[0];
    $dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tmp));

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$dob', '$salt', NOW())");

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {

        // get user details
        $result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

        // return user details
        return mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the $str_birthday is `27-03-1982` then it should be stored in the MySQL database as `1982-03-27`. But whatever the input date is, I only get `1969-12-31` in the database. What is wrong with my code?

**Added**
I created an index.html file to check out the JSON response. Here's the index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
Tag: <input type="text" name="tag"><br>
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
Birthday: <input type="date" name="birthday"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the index.php file that gets POST variables and gets JSON responses.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && !empty($_POST['tag'])) {

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // get the variables.
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];

    echo $birthday;

    // response Array
    $response = array("error" => FALSE);

    require_once 'mysql/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    if ($tag == 'register') {

        // check if user is already exists

        if ($db->userExists($email)) {

            // user already exists - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already exists";

            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {

            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password, $gender, $birthday);

            if ($user) {
                // user successfully saved to MySQL database
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];
                $response["user"]["birthday"] = $user["birthday"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];

                echo json_encode($response);

            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "JSON Error occured in Registration";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Operation failed due to the missing tag!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST);
?>
```

And finally here's the JSON response I got from directly typing each value in index.html file.

```
{"error":false,"uid":"564901af9bb9f2.79708336","user":{"name":"Learning PHP","email":"learning@php.com","gender":"","birthday":"1969-12-31","created_at":"2015-11-15 17:05:35","updated_at":null}}string(4) "POST" array(5) { ["tag"]=> string(8) "register" ["name"]=> string(12) "Learning PHP" ["email"]=> string(16) "learning@php.com" ["password"]=> string(11) "learningphp" ["dob"]=> string(10) "1981-10-12" }
```

So, it seems like there's no problem of getting the POST variable of 'birthday', but the thing is the return value. 1969-12-31.

Comment: what contains in your $dob

Comment: What mysql data type is the birthday column? Please post a) a birthdate b) the sql statement "insert into..." for that birthdate

Comment: @maxhb It's already in the question - `$result = mysqli_query($this->db->connect(), "INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$dob', '$salt', NOW())");`

Comment: @maxhb and the data format of the birthday field is date.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer what is the value of $tmp before the strtotime() call? The 1969-12-31 date is the result of 0 being passed to the date() function.

Comment: why are you splitting the date string? what is the result if you try `$dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str_birthday));`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity that also returns `1969-12-31`.. It drives me really crazy.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer, are you sure the `$str_birthday` is in this format `D-M-YYYY` with the `-` character as a delimiter?, because if the delimiter is `/` for example, the output will be as you said `1969-12-31`

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yes, I get the date variable in a string format from Android clients. In Java code I defined the date format as `String format = "dd-MM-yyyy";`

Comment: it should work correctly then http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/uhgn-ayk3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big clue is the date that's being returned.  `1969-12-31` is probably `1970-01-01` in some negative timezone (e.g. GMT-05).  And `1970-01-01` is Unix timestamp 0.

The problem here is that the `date` function, in it's second parameter, is expecting a Unix timestamp - a numeric value.  But you're passing a date string.  PHP doesn't know what to do with the string so it converts it to 0 and then `date()` takes that zero and returns the date you are seeing.

In fact, you don't need all the splitting and combining etc.  You should be able to pass `$str_birthday` straight into the database if it's already formatted at YYYY-MM-DD.

Unrelated but even more important: Building SQL strings as you have is very ill advised.  You are opening yourself up to SQL Injection attacks.  For example if `$name="');drop table users` then you are in deep trouble.  You should use mysqli_prepare instead.  Here is some recommended reading about [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: None of these worked.. it really drives me crazy. Perhaps I need to explain the environment that I'm working in. I'm working with the webserver called 000webhost.com. There are version gaps of PHP and MySQL between the web server and my computer. The PHP version that the web server uses is 5.2, while my computer has 5.5.29 and the MySQL version of the web server is 5.1. Does this explain why some commands do not perform well as expected?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "none of these worked".  Try entering `$dob = "2015-11-15"` before your query statement and see if that's the date you get out.

Comment: if I replace that `$str_birthday` variable with a hardcoded variable, for example, `1982-04-17`, the date is successfully stored.

Comment: Try this: `$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str_birthday); $dob = $dob->format('Y-m'd');`

Comment: That did not work either.. I uploaded more information on the question and could you please read that? Maybe there might be some keys..

Comment: What you uploaded doesn't make much sense to me.  The output shows `["dob"]=> string(10) "1981-10-12"` that value can be inserted directly into the database.

Comment: You're definitely right. I also believe that's the way it should work, but somehow it doesn't make sense at all. even though I directly store the `$birthday` variable into MySQL database (the data type the birthday field is `DATE`), it still returns `1969-12-31`. I really can't figure out why.

Comment: Print out the value of your SQL (`"INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, birthday, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$dob', '$salt', NOW())"`) so you can see what's actually being executed.

Comment: I also tried to work with that method you suggested above - `$dob = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str_birthday); $dob = $dob->format('Y-m'd');` but it also led me to something never expected. My Eclipse recognises `DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $str_birthday);` but it says that the `->format()` part is undefined.

Comment: `1969-12-31` is the result that is stored in MySQL database, whatever the input date is.

Comment: The data types of the other fields are all `VARCHAR`, while the data type of the `birthday` is `DATE` and the data type of the `created_at` is `DATETIME`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95193/discussion-between-oz-solomon-and-newbieprogrammer).